# How to auto generate excel links between worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel for MAC version 15.40.

Have TWO worksheets in the same workbook with data relevant to each.

The first sheet has a list of names. There is sum of the number of times those name appear in 'column F'.

The second sheet has a list of those same names located in 'column A' but listed multiple times and with some merged cells both because of different data.

I would like to know how I could auto generate links between the numbers in 'column F' of sheet 'List Name' to the first instance of the respective name in sheet 'List Data' - 'column A' location A##.

Example:

List Name:
name '11111abvls3' next to it is numeral '2' because it appears twice in sheet 2. Click on the '2' and it takes you to sheet 'List Data' at the first instance of '11111abvls3' at sheet 'List Data' place 'A5'.

I have added some pictures:

```
[Book 1 List Name sheet List Name][1]
[Book 1 List Data sheet List Data][2]
[Excel error message][3]

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMJVI.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtJvO.png
 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V8z0.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the Hyperlink function with Match inside in column F with something like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("[book1.xlsx]sheet2! A" & MATCH (A1, Sheet2! A: A, 0), "number value")
```

`book1.xlsx` is your filename

Sheet2 is your sheet2

"Number value" is the formula that calculates your sum of the names and is the "friendly name" that is shown in the cell.

Comment: I made some edits and added some pictures to help. The formula provided didn't work. Excel had to auto correct it.